# htaccess mod_rewrite q, lets users see non existing page

Tags: .htaccess

So I have the following in my .htaccess for my mod_rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?a=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]*)$ /product.php?p=$1 [L]
```

It let's me have /help instead of .index.php?a=help but the problem is that if someone visits /blahblah is doesn't give an error, it just displays a blank index page with nothing on it except the logo, sidebar and blank content space.

Any ideas how to stop this? I was gonna use php if() but that seems to cumbersome because I have to do it every time I add a page. Any way with .htaccess?

Comment: Have you defined ErrorDocument 404, 500 etc..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use php here. Your `index.php` reads the `$_GET['a']` variable and determines what content to render. But mod_rewrite has zero knowledge of what is or what isn't renderable content by the `index.php` file.

The implementation will depend on how your `index.php` is written. If you can't find the page denoted by the "a" parameter, then it's up to `index.php` to return a 404 result. There's no way to do this in htaccess.